# Xpath - extract only numbers

Tags: xpath, xml-parsing, google-sheets, google-docs, xpath-2.0

Using Xpath in Google Docs spreadsheet, I need to extract only the numbers (digits) from a  containing both text and numbers using Xmlimport. I've been trying to find a solution on stackoverflow and google, but so far unsuccessful.

This is what I have in the field I2 in the spreadsheet:

```
=IMPORTXML(J2; "//*[@id='tab-1411393574769-10']/div[2]/div/table[1]/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]")
```

so far it returns this string: `152 text`

I really need it to return only: `152`

How would I construct this command in Google Docs? I tried putting SUM() around the entire thing to see if it would return just the digits, but it returns: `0`

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try extracting the digits with regexextract and see if that works ?

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(IMPORTXML(J2; "//*[@id='tab-1411393574769-10']/div[2]/div/table[1]/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]"); "(\d+)")
```

Comment: THAT WORKED! Thank you so much! Sorry I can't upvote just yet - I still need 2 points to do so. As soon as I have them I will upvote :) Would you mind explaining what this part does: "(\d+)"? Once again, thank you.

Comment: \d a shorthand character class, which matches all numbers; it is the same as [0-9].
+ means: one or more of the expression
This is placed in a capturing group ().